# What is the name of the ambiguity in "he loves a woman"?

Tags: ambiguity, semantics, linguistics

[What Are Scope Ambiguities?](https://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/projects/milca/courses/comsem/html/node92.html) has the example

> *Every man loves a woman.*

And says that it is scopally ambiguous because these two possible readings exist:

1. "for every man, there is a woman, and it's possible that each man loves a different woman"
2. "there is one particular woman who is loved by every man"

Apparently this is because *every man loves a woman* contains scope ambiguity. Is this because of the quantifiers *every* and *a* ? Or just *every* ? (Is *a* a quantifier?)

Then, what type of ambiguity do these other readings result from (the second is a restatement of (1) above):

3. Every man loves *one* woman each
4. Every man loves *at least one woman* each

Comment: It's because of the quantifiers. _Every_ is universal, whereas _some/a_ is existential, and having both in the same sentence generates ambiguities. Much the same when you have a negative and a modal in the same sentence; negatives, modals, and quantifiers are Operators, with scopes and focus constituents that can get very confused. The more Operators you use, the more ambiguity you generate.

Comment: @JohnLawler my question is, what is the name of the ambiguity that gives "he loves a woman" two readings, "he loves one woman", "he loves several women"

Comment: Ambiguities don't always have specific names. Call it a quantifier ambiguity. And those aren't the only meanings.

Comment: Why don't you like *scope ambiguity*?

Comment: @StuartF How can it be? There are no competing operators or scopes (as far as I can tell).